# How to create an air-free design?

Tags: 3d-design

I am creating a bottlecap-like design. The design is sealed by rotating the lid. I am adding a chemical to it for an experiment. I would like the inside of the design to have no air circulating to it through the lid tiny spaces.

My design:

[image]

Are there any simple solutions I can implement out there? Design-wise, material-wise, or maybe an extra piece?

Comment: Are you talking about sealing design or porosity of the objects when printed (it looks like the final sentence above the image hints to that)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any simple solutions I can implement out there?

A gasket made of rubber or other elastic or deformable material is probably the best option. Printing one or both of the parts using a deformable material like TPU might also work. Finally, if you don't need to open the unit during the experiment, you could use a sealant like silicone caulk might make sense.

Comment: Or a garden hose o-ring.

Comment: @caleb How about the air that is in before it is closed. is there a way to force it out?

Comment: @AnwarElhadad You could fill and close the device in an inert gas environment, like nitrogen, CO2, or argon. Or you could add a valve that lets you pump the air out after filling. I’m not sure that a FDM printed part would hold a vacuum — you’ll need to test that and perhaps take steps to seal the inside.